gtsummary::modify_header(): ! Error in the argument statistic for variable "age". ℹ Value must be a named list of functions
Age is a numeric and continuous variable.
gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    by = variable_x,
    include = c(age, sex, bmibl),  # Variables to summarize
    type = list(c(bmibl, age) ~ "continuous",
                sex ~ "categorical"  ),
    statistic = list(
      age ~ "{mean} ({sd})",  # Specify mean and SD for age
      bmibl ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
      all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)" # Counts (percentages) for categorical variables
    ),
    digits = list(
      all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1)  # 0 decimal for counts, 1 for percentages
    ),
    missing = "no" 
)

If I do remove age and bmibl from the list I get default stats, that are not in the mean(sd) format. This error only shows up on one of my instances of R and not on the other, both are running the same version of R and gtsummary.

Without a minimal reproducible example, it's going to be difficult to assist you. Here are details on how to create one. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

this is how a head(mydata) looks like:
AGE BMIBL SEX   id
78  25.6 M     007
75  28.2 F     019
52  27.7 M     014
71  NA   M     001
68  40.6 M    010
76  27.9 F     002
